# converting a javascript object returned from a javascript API to a dart class

Tags: dart, dart-js-interop

I'm trying to create a dart implementation of the auth0 javascript API using the js package from https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/js.

so I'm loading https://cdn.auth0.com/js/lock/10.0.0/lock.min.js in the index.html and I created the following auth0lock dart class:

```
@JS()
library auth0lock;

import 'package:js/js.dart';

@JS('Auth0Lock') 
class Auth0LockJS {
  external factory Auth0LockJS(String token, String domain, Object options);
  external on(String event, Function func);
  external show();
}

class Auth0Lock {
  Auth0LockJS auth0;
  Auth0Lock(String token, String domain, Object options) {
    this.auth0 = new Auth0LockJS(token,domain,options);
  }
  on(String event, Function func) {
    this.auth0.on(event,allowInterop(func));
  }
  show() {
    this.auth0.show();
  }
}

@anonymous
@JS()
class AuthResult {
 external factory AuthResult({
  String accessToken,
  String idToken,
  String idTokenPayload,
  String state
});
  external String get accessToken;
  external set accessToken(String v);
  external String get idToken;
  external set idToken(String v);
  external Object get idTokenPayload;
  external set idTokenPayload(Object v);
  external String get state;
  external set state(String v);
}
```

I'm writing an angular2-dart application so  I created an authentication service that uses the `auth0lock.dart` file that I showed previously using the following code:

```
@Injectable()
class Auth {
    Auth0Lock lock;

    authenticatedEvent(AuthResult authResult) {
      print(authResult);
    }

    Auth() {
        this.lock = new Auth0Lock(configObj.auth0.apiKey, configObj.auth0.domain,{});
        this.lock.on("authenticated", authenticatedEvent);
    }
    updateProfileName(data) {
      var profile = data['profile'] != null ? data['profile'] : data;
      print(profile['name']);
    }

    authenticated() {
      return false;
    }

    login() {
       this.lock.show();
    }
}
```

now... everything actually works! I created in the `auth_service.dart` file a variable typed `AuthLock` named `lock`. I instance is with parameters, run the `show()` function, connect to the `authenticated` event and the function is fired with the authentication is completed.

I created a class AuthResult but it ignores it and I get a javascript object returned from the function handler.

I program the code using Intellij and execute with dartium. so when I place a breakpoint on the `print(authResult);`line in the `auth_service.dart` file, the debugger shows that the authResult Object contains 2 properties, `JavaScript View` of type `Object` and `class` of type `JSObjectimpl`. the `Javascript View` contains all the properties that are returned by this function handler.

how do I convert it to a regular class in dart ? obviously I created the AuthResult class wrong cause the function handler doesn't return this type. so what am I missing?

thanks!

## update

inside the `authenticatedEvent` function I tried printing `authResult.values`, that produced the error that a class of type JSObjectImpl doesn't have that function. so the return object is type `JSObjectImpl`. the weird thing is that I have no idea where `JSObjectImpl` is defined so I removed the variable type of `authResult` and tried to use the variables inside directory with the following code:

```
authenticatedEvent(authResult) {
  var a = authResult.accessToken;
  print(a);
}
```

this works. why I can't find `JSObjectImpl` type in dart? any quick way to convert this to a dart class?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you just need to remove `@anonymous` from `AuthResult`

A simplified but complete and similar example

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      var Apple = function(type) {
        this.type = type;
        this.color = "red";
        this.getInfo2 = function() {
          return this.color + ' ' + this.type + ' apple';
        };
      };

      Apple.prototype.getInfo = function() {
        return this.color + ' ' + this.type + ' apple';
      };

      function callback(f) {
        console.log(f);
        f(new Apple('Golden Delicious'));
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="application/dart" src="index.dart"></script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**index.dart**

```
@JS()
library typed_callback.web;

import 'package:js/js.dart';

@JS()
class Apple {
  external String get type;
  external set type(String type);
  external String get color;
  external set color(String color);
  external String getInfo();
  external String getInfo2();
  external Apple(String type);
}

typedef void Callback(Apple a);

@JS('callback')
external void callback(Callback /* or just Function */ f);

f(Apple apple) {
  print(apple.getInfo());
  print(apple); // prints the stringified JS object [object Object]
}

main() async {
  callback(allowInterop(f));
}
```

Comment: Hi. thanks for your help. unfortunately removing the @anonymous tag doesn't resolve the issue. the AuthResult that i'm getting is a json object not a class. i'm wondering how to convert it to a dart class.

Comment: In my example what is passed to `Apple` also looks like a JS object when printed but can be used like a Dart class. I don't think there is a way to create real Dart class. All you get is s proxy that allows you to access properties and methods like it were a Dart class.